# How to make WordPress customizable for clients

Tags: plugins, widgets

I was wondering how I can make WordPress customizable for clients? Such as, I use classes and ids in my span, paragraph, div, (etc.) elements... so how do I do this customization without having the client know about tags and classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress define the [Customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) for doing this job. It works in frontend, on default, and you can enhance with your requirements. Also give it easier possibility to live preview of the options. 
You find a lot of how to here on WPSE and also in the wild of the www.

Comment: I currently have created a child theme with Genesis and have the front end looking like it should... but it is using paragraph, span, and div tags with classes and ids in them. Is there any way to dynamically wrap the elements in div tags with specific classes or will I have to rework it?

Comment: Yes, you can enhance the body tag via hook to create custom class. This should be usable as first identifier.